Resource service in the standalone .NET Aspire Dashboard
I'm trying to enable the resources UI in the standalone mode .NET Aspire Dashboard (built via Docker). I found in the documentation that this can be achieved by adding specific option to the configuration. I'm doing that by setting environment variables in the docker-compose (the first container):
services:
  aspire-dashboard:
    container_name: "aspire-dashboard"
    image: "mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspire-dashboard:8.0"
    environment:
      DOTNET_DASHBOARD_UNSECURED_ALLOW_ANONYMOUS: "true"
      DASHBOARD__RESOURCESERVICECLIENT__AUTHMODE: "ApiKey"
      DASHBOARD__RESOURCESERVICECLIENT__APIKEY: "1234567"
      DASHBOARD__RESOURCESERVICECLIENT__URL: "http://localhost:20213"
    ports:
    - target: 18888
      published: 18888
    restart: unless-stopped
  cache:
    container_name: "cache"
    image: "docker.io/library/redis:7.4"
    environment:
      OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_ENDPOINT: "http://aspire-dashboard:18889"
      OTEL_SERVICE_NAME: "cache"
    ports:
    - target: 6379
      published: 6379
    restart: unless-stopped
  apiservice:
    container_name: "apiservice"
    image: "apiservice:latest"
    environment:
      OTEL_DOTNET_EXPERIMENTAL_OTLP_EMIT_EXCEPTION_LOG_ATTRIBUTES: "true"
      OTEL_DOTNET_EXPERIMENTAL_OTLP_EMIT_EVENT_LOG_ATTRIBUTES: "true"
      OTEL_DOTNET_EXPERIMENTAL_OTLP_RETRY: "in_memory"
      ASPNETCORE_FORWARDEDHEADERS_ENABLED: "true"
      HTTP_PORTS: "8080"
      OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_ENDPOINT: "http://aspire-dashboard:18889"
      OTEL_SERVICE_NAME: "apiservice"
    ports:
    - target: 8080
      published: 10000
    - target: 8443
      published: 10001
    restart: unless-stopped
  aspirestudyexternalapi:
    container_name: "aspirestudyexternalapi"
    image: "aspire-study-external-api:latest"
    environment:
      OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_ENDPOINT: "http://aspire-dashboard:18889"
      OTEL_SERVICE_NAME: "aspirestudyexternalapi"
    ports:
    - target: 8080
      published: 5000
    restart: unless-stopped
  webfrontend:
    container_name: "webfrontend"
    image: "webfrontend:latest"
    environment:
      OTEL_DOTNET_EXPERIMENTAL_OTLP_EMIT_EXCEPTION_LOG_ATTRIBUTES: "true"
      OTEL_DOTNET_EXPERIMENTAL_OTLP_EMIT_EVENT_LOG_ATTRIBUTES: "true"
      OTEL_DOTNET_EXPERIMENTAL_OTLP_RETRY: "in_memory"
      ASPNETCORE_FORWARDEDHEADERS_ENABLED: "true"
      HTTP_PORTS: "8080"
      ConnectionStrings__cache: "cache:6379"
      services__apiservice__http__0: "http://apiservice:8080"
      services__aspirestudyexternalapi__http__0: "http://aspirestudyexternalapi:8080"
      OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_ENDPOINT: "http://aspire-dashboard:18889"
      OTEL_SERVICE_NAME: "webfrontend"
    ports:
    - target: 8080
      published: 10002
    - target: 8443
      published: 10003
    restart: unless-stopped

Unfortunately, even though the resource and the console tab has appeared in the dashboard page, the application is throwing error:
aspire-dashboard  | fail: Aspire.Dashboard.Model.DashboardClient[0]
aspire-dashboard  |       Error #1 watching resources.
aspire-dashboard  |       Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode="Unimplemented", Detail="Service is unimplemented.")
aspire-dashboard  |          at Grpc.Net.Client.Internal.Retry.RetryCallBaseClientStreamReader`2.MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
aspire-dashboard  |          at Grpc.Core.AsyncStreamReaderExtensions.ReadAllAsyncCore[T](IAsyncStreamReader`1 streamReader, CancellationToken cancellationToken)+MoveNext()
aspire-dashboard  |          at Grpc.Core.AsyncStreamReaderExtensions.ReadAllAsyncCore[T](IAsyncStreamReader`1 streamReader, CancellationToken cancellationToken)+System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource<System.Boolean>.GetResult()
aspire-dashboard  |          at Aspire.Dashboard.Model.DashboardClient.<>c__DisplayClass27_1.<<EnsureInitialized>g__WatchResourcesAsync|5>d.MoveNext() in /_/src/Aspire.Dashboard/Model/DashboardClient.cs:line 293
aspire-dashboard  |       --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
aspire-dashboard  |          at Aspire.Dashboard.Model.DashboardClient.<>c__DisplayClass27_1.<<EnsureInitialized>g__WatchResourcesAsync|5>d.MoveNext() in /_/src/Aspire.Dashboard/Model/DashboardClient.cs:line 293
aspire-dashboard  |       --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
aspire-dashboard  |          at Aspire.Dashboard.Model.DashboardClient.<>c__DisplayClass27_0.<<EnsureInitialized>g__WatchResourcesWithRecoveryAsync|3>d.MoveNext() in /_/src/Aspire.Dashboard/Model/DashboardClient.cs:line 274

To be honest, I'm not even sure it is possible to get the result I described above. Has anyone tried to achieve something like this?

Where will the dashboard get the resource info from? You specified http://localhost:20213 but the error seems to suggest whatever runs there returned Unimplemented

I specified http://localhost:20213 just like in the launchSettings.json of the AppHost project (.NET Aspire Starter App). I thought maybe the service starts by itself, but seems it doesn't. I'm going to try to add another one project to orchestration as GRPC server.

Some service is running on that port and returns Unimplemented
